# On my Facebook Job App, what does "Location" mean?

Tags: applications

Under "Contact Info", there's a field simply titled "Location". Is that supposed to mean my home address? The place I'm currently filling in this application from? Please someone clarify, preferably who has filled in that or a similar form before.

[image: Screenshot of relevant section in application]

Comment: Your current location (City, State) I believe will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

They expect the **City, State and Country** of where you currently live and/or work.

99.9% of the time, if someone wants your exact address, they'll provide multiple fields like street address, postal code, state, country.

Simply providing a single field titled "location" should be assumed to mean they don't want anything more specific than a city.

This is generally assumed to be the place you'll be spending most days for the next few months - it wouldn't make much sense to fill in the location where you're currently on a week-long holiday or where you'll be moving away from in a week, nor where you're originally from if you won't be spending much, if any, time there for the foreseeable future, for example.